# careers signup - validation wording error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

in careers 2.0 on the My Profile page.

when you click on the technology dislikes

the help popup that is displayed says the following:

"List 5 technologies that you are dealbreakers for you."

Doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!  Thanks for pointing it out.